# Is this a file permission or coding error in PHP using file_put_contents?

Tags: php

So what I was trying to do was to build a custom CMS using PHP. I pretty much had it in mind that I would store the HTML/Javascript strings and then concatenate them together to form a new page, then using PHP with file_put_contents and directory explore, etc... this would work.

I was trying a basic example out and this wasn't overwriting the file:

There are two files, change_file.php is the one with the code below, and test-file.txt is a simple text file with the words "Test file" inside.

```
<?php
  error_reporting(-1);

  // simple test
  $file = 'test-file.txt';
  $mod_file = file_get_contents($file);
  $mod_file .= "appended";              // appending line
  file_put_contents($file, $mod_file);
  echo $mod_file;
?>
```

So I'd run the above once which would output "Test file appended", and then comment out the appending line, and refresh the page, but it stills shows "Test file" there are no errors.

Am I missing something obvious here? Like I can't just write to a public directory without permissions or something? This is in /var/www/html/test-folder

Comment: This example work for me. For you, wrong permissions could be a case. What if you write not in the same file you read. e.g $file2 = "test-file2.txt" will this file written?

Comment: @sebkrueger thanks I'll check that out, if it was a file permission problem what would I have to do to write in the public-web directory? What I was aiming to do was to replace the current index file on the root folder of a website, with a new page.

Comment: What you have to do, to write in the web-dir of your server, depend much on the config. I think i know what you aiming to, but first I would make sure, that Webserver+PHP process have the rights to write a complete new file inside the folder.

Comment: @sebkrueger so I did the test, the new file did not show up, no errors either, why are there no errors like a permission error?

Comment: Where are you looking for errros? Is display errors set `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ?

Comment: I think errors are working, I've seen them before. I should try to break something on purpose to see errors working with the error code above.